# Retrieve URL of Script/Style and Dependencies

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts

**Given script X Y and Z how would I get the list in PHP of X Y Z and their dependencies?**

I need to load several scripts that have dependencies.

Normally I would do this via `wp_enqueue_script` but in this situation I need to load these scripts in a shadow DOM for a webcomponent, and cannot rely on `wp_head` and `wp_footer`, I have to construct the DOM elements myself in JS. This is so that the contents of the component are isolated from the rest of the page for styling purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` both use [`WP_Dependencies::add()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_dependencies/add/) which initializes a new instance of [`_WP_Dependency`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/_wp_dependency/) (see [`wp_scripts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_scripts/) and [`wp_styles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_styles/)), so all the script's dependencies are stored in the `deps` property of the class instance.

However, that property only stores the *handle* names of the script's dependencies, e.g. `jquery-migrate` and `jquery-core` for the default/core jQuery script (handle name: `jquery`), so to get the actual URL of a dependency file (script/stylesheet), we would need to use [`WP_Dependencies::all_deps()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_dependencies/all_deps/) and then loop through `WP_Dependencies::$to_do` to get the dependency's `src` value:

```php
// Enqueue a script:
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', '/path/to/file.js', [ 'jquery' ] );

// Get all its dependencies:
wp_scripts()->all_deps( 'my-script' );
foreach ( wp_scripts()->to_do as $handle ) {
    $dep = wp_scripts()->registered[ $handle ];
    var_dump( $dep->handle, $dep->src );
    // or do something with $dep->src ...
}

// Enqueue a style:
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', '/path/to/file.css', [ 'foo-dep' ] );

// Get all its dependencies:
wp_styles()->all_deps( 'my-style' );
foreach ( wp_styles()->to_do as $handle ) {
    $dep = wp_styles()->registered[ $handle ];
    var_dump( $dep->handle, $dep->src );
    // or do something with $dep->src ...
}
```

Note that the `$dep->src` can be a `false` if the *dependency* contains a dependency, e.g. the default `jquery` handle which has `jquery-migrate` as a dependency. (But don't worry, the dependencies will be in the `to_do` array.) And secondly, the `to_do` array also includes the actual file, e.g. `file.js` in the above example.

Comment: Ah this looks promising! I'll  need to refactor it to allow for recursion for the dependencies of dependencies though, give me a few hours to test out

Comment: Sure, take your time. :)

Comment: I tested this out and produced 2 functions, and can confirm this does what it says on the tin, sorry it took so long but thanks!!!